# need to override inline css

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, builder

I am having a problem in a wordpress site I am building using **iThemes Builder**.

When I add the plugin **Jquery Megamenu**, the drop down is cut off by an *overflow:hidden* property, which I cannot seem to override in my custom css (using !important etc).

I was advised that a possible solution would be to write some Jquery to override the inline style, but I am not sure how to proceed. could anybody help?

You can view the site here http://www.labratrecords.com, the megamenu is the second one down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're best going through a jQuery tutorial first to understand what you're doing (here's one from the horses mouth http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works), but to set the inline css of an element you can do this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).ready(function () {

    $('#elementID').css('overflow', 'visible');

  }
</script>
```

You can replace "#elementID" with any css selector (including one that selects many elements). e.g

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'visible');

$('h2').css('overflow', 'visible');    

$('#toolbar a').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

**More background**
Even before looking at jQuery (which is a javascript library) it's good to get a grips of javascript on it's own. He's a brief, but well written intro tutorial from the chocolate factory:
http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/intro-to-js.html

Comment: OK great thanks Ed, I'll have a read of this and see if I can work it out. (I'm not a programmer, but doing the site as a favour for a friend, hence the stupid questions.)

One thing I'm not quite understanding though, is where I put this code?

Thanks again :)

Comment: The updated code I've added can go straight into the header of the html file. The first line includes the jQuery library (you can remove this if you've already included it). The remaining lines are the javascript code, like css it can be placed within the html file or moved out to separate file. I've just changed the js code a little to use ".ready()" instead of ".load()".

Comment: Thanks Ed, very much appreciate your help. Will let you know how I get on. Tom

Comment: I've added another item to your reading list - see update answer.

Comment: Ed, Thanks for the further info, I have started reading and I understand what the code you've kindly written is doing, but having a little trouble understanding it in the context of the tools I have available in Builder. Through the editor I have access to the php and css files, but no html - do I need to create a new html file or is there something I'm missing here?
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No the php outputs the html (this allows the server to output different information when it/you wants not just a static file). Most likely within the  php file there is a section where the html header file is defined, you need to add this code here.

Comment: OK, I'm with you now, and have located this in the header.php file - <?php wp_head(); //we need this for plugins ?>

</head>

Comment: Ok what seems to be happening is the outer containing divs are still set to hidden so the script is having no effect - how would I go about changing the property for these as well? I have examined the code in the source but the containers all seem to have complex long names...

Comment: the element style of the outermost container always says overflow:hidden no matter what I do... I have no idea.
It's fine if you can't help me beyond this point I realise this is going on a bit now.

Comment: $('*').css('overflow', 'visible'); will select everything. I'm not recommending it for your final version, but you can try it and check if it's actually your problem.

Comment: Ok I've done that and i'm still seeing overflow:hidden all over, so I'm thinking the code is in the wrong place. I've put it in header.php near the bottom, within the <head> tag and above <?php wp_head(); //we need this for plugins ?>...

Comment: How are you viewing the "overflow:hidden", using web inspector/firebug or are you just clicking "view source"? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebug - the property is always attached to 'element.style' no matter what I seem to do...

Comment: Do you get the right look/behaviour when you set the css elements in firebug/web inspector? There's no point searching the server side code if the css isn't incorrect in the first place! It sounds like some javascript is setting the inline values *after* you are. You'll need to find were this is happening. If this is the case you might need to learn a little more php to find where it's taking place. This may then lead you to ask questions on php. Don't forget to assign an answer to this original question if there is a correct one here :)

Comment: Thanks Ed - I've got a friend helping out at the mo, I'll post up any solutions we find